# Not able to set value in JSTL

Tags: jstl

from ajax response i am getting json string:

```
{"{\"nodeName\":\"abc\"}":[{"url":"abc","status":true},{"url":"abc","status":true}],"      {\"nodeName\":\"pqr\"}":[{"url":"abc","status":true},{"url":"abc","status":true}]}
```

and i am parsing that json string from below mentioned code:

```
$.each(obj, function(key, arr) {
    $.each(arr, function(_, v) {
        alert(key +" "+ v.url +" "+v.status);
    });
});
```

till now it works fine.

Now, using jstl i am setting the value of key, v.url and v.status inside `$.each` like this

```
<c:set var="status" value="${v.status}"/> 
<c:set var="url" value="${v.url}"/>  
<c:set var="nodeName" value="${key}"/>
```

alert("url =" +'${status}' + " key =" + '${nodeName}' + " status ="+ '${url}');

i am able to get the value of key(${nodeName}) on alert but no value for url and status.

Please suggest..

Comment: Where is this `v` ? In which scope it is - `request`, `session` , `page` or `context` ?

Comment: i have used this c:set code inside  $.each(arr, function(_, v) {
        alert(key +" "+ v.url +" "+v.status);
    });
i have not set any scope for v

Comment: i have chnaged my approach instead of jstl i am using javascript condition. thanks ......